# astro: issue with class and className on deployment

Tags: typescript, astrojs

I'm trying to deploy my Astro project with Typescript using `npm run build` as always but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
src/pages/topics/index.astro:14:12 - error ts(2322): Type '{ children: Element[]; class: string; }' is not assignable to type 
'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'.
  Property 'class' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>, HTMLElement>'. Did you mean 'className'?

14   <section class="my-8">
```

Here is the code, i'm using `class` as usual in an .astro component. The error is saying to use className (which is wrong for an .astro component) so I don't know if it's a bug or what.

```
  <section class="my-8">
    <RoutePath paths={["Home", "Topics"]} />
    <h1 class="text-[1.8rem] my-5 block font-semibold">Topics</h1>
    <hr />
    <TopicPosts />
  </section>
```

Comment: That sounds like a React error, so maybe it thinks that component is a React component? Are you using react in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm using React, but no worries I found the issue. It was a bug that I solved by re-installing the dependencies again. However, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Remove the files "package-lock.json" and "node_modules" and then on the terminal type "npm install"